# How to filter date my DGV in VB?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I wanna filter my DGV table by date. My Date column is date type.

For example, if i choose the month combobox (PilihBulan) September and choose the year combobox (PilihTahun) 2014, when I click the button1, the DGV will show list september 2014 only.

all this time, i tried filter with string format like this:
DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Tanggal like '%{0}%' ", KotakCari.Text)

this is my screenshoot form:
http://i706.photobucket.com/albums/ww64/dhezna/menu/4332400000_zps021d4fbe.jpg

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub PilihBulan_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PilihBulan.SelectedIndexChanged
    If PilihTahun.Text = "" Then
        If PilihBulan.Text = "Januari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jan-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Februari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Feb-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Maret" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Mar-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "April" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Apr-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Mei" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-May-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juni" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jun-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juli" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jul-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Agustus" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Aug-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "September" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Sep-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Oktober" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Oct-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "November" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Nov-"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Desember" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Dec-"
        End If

    ElseIf PilihTahun.Text = "2014" Then
        If PilihBulan.Text = "Januari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jan-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Februari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Feb-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Maret" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Mar-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "April" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Apr-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Mei" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-May-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juni" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jun-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juli" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jul-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Agustus" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Aug-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "September" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Sep-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Oktober" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Oct-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "November" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Nov-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Desember" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Dec-2014"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PilihTahun_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PilihTahun.SelectedIndexChanged
    If PilihTahun.Text = "2014" Then
        If PilihBulan.Text = "Januari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jan-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Februari" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Feb-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Maret" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Mar-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "April" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Apr-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Mei" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-May-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juni" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jun-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Juli" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Jul-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Agustus" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Aug-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "September" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Sep-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Oktober" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Oct-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "November" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Nov-2014"
        ElseIf PilihBulan.Text = "Desember" Then
            KotakCari.Text = "-Dec-2014"
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DGV.DataSource = (ds.Tables("LapTransaksiSimpanan"))

    If PilihTipe.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Pilih kategori dulu!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Pilih Kategori")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf KotakCari.Text = "" Or PilihTipe.Text = "----lihat semua----" Then
        Call TampilGrid()
    Else
        Dim DV As New DataView(DGV.DataSource)
        If PilihTipe.Text = "Tanggal" Then
            If PilihBulan.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Pilih bulan dulu!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Pilih Bulan")
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf PilihTahun.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Pilih tahun dulu!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Pilih Tahun")
                Exit Sub
            Else
                DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Tanggal like '%{0}%' ", KotakCari.Text)
                DV.RowFilter = Date.Today
                DGV.DataSource = DV
                DGV.ReadOnly = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your `DataTable` contains `Date` values or `String` representations of dates?  If it's the former then you have to actually filter by date, which means no `LIKE` with wildcards because that's only for text.  If it's the latter then WHY would do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `DataTable` contains `Date` values and not `String` representations of dates, which you should start by fixing if it's not already, then you should populate your `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid.  When you want to filter you do like this:

```
Dim year As Integer 'Set the year based on one ComboBox.
Dim month As Integer 'Set the month baesd on the other ComboBox, 1-12.

Dim startDate As New Date(year, month, 1)
Dim endDate As New Date(year, month, Date.DaysInMonth(year, month))

Me.BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("DateColumn >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND DateColumn <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#",
                                         startDate,
                                         endDate)
```

You may be able to use `BETWEEN` instead but I always forget what's inclusive and what's exclusive for that.

Comment: what is BindingSource1?
where i must declare BindingSource1?